# Counting How Many the Cluster Index

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means, counting

I am doing clustering with k-means, and here is the code:

`[g c] = kmeans(data,k,'dist','SqEuclidean');`

g is the cluster index

c is the centroid

k is the number of clusters, I input '3' in it.

When the code is executed, here is the sample result:

```
40    60    69     1
50    75    78     2
65    70    75     2
79    80    72     3
88    80    80     3
36    67    66     1
40    60    69     1
77    85    65     3
76    77    79     3
```

My question is, how to count the cluster index for each cluster? What script I should write to show this thing:

"Cluster1 has three members
Cluster2 has two members
Cluster3 has four members"

I'm getting confused because the cluster index only have one variable. Any idea?

Thank you. Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the blog post [Under-appreciated accumarray](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/02/20/under-appreciated-accumarray/), this can be done neatly like so:

```
clust = [1; 2; 2; 3; 3; 1; 1; 3; 3]; % your data
accumarray(clust, ones(size(clust)))

ans =

 3
 2
 4
```

Comment: I wrote the code: `clust = g; accumarray(clust, ones(size(clust)))` so it is more efficient because I have more than 100 data. Again, thank you. :)